# Using VBA Combobox value in SQL Query returning type mismatch

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have a user form that contains a list of agents. When you click on an agent and click a button to mark them as not here, a popup comes up that requires you to pick a reason they aren't here.

This popup also contains a box that should display the current amount of attendance points the agent has. The code to pull that info from the SQL table where it's stored is below.

When it runs I get a *type mismatch* error on the `.additem rs![Five9 Extension]` line. The column on the SQL table is a `varchar` and I just need it to display a number so I'm not really sure what the issue is.

```vb
Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim Server_Name As String
Dim Database_Name As String
Dim SQLStr As String
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

Server_Name = "SDL02-VM25"
Database_Name = "PIA"
SQLStr = "select [Five9 Extension] from dbo.[Master Staffing List] Where [Agent Name] ='" & MainPage.AgentName.Selected(itemIndex) & "'"

Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & ""
rs.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenStatic

With ReasonPopup.CurPoints
    .Clear
    Do
        .AddItem rs![Five9 Extension]
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop Until rst.EOF
End With

rs.Close
Cn.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set Cn = Nothing
Exit Sub
```

Comment: What does `rs.Fields("Five9 Extension").Value` return? Could it be `NULL`?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean? I'm not sure where I would put that code to test it.

Comment: Break (F9) on the `With` block, run the code, then when the breakpoint is hit bring up the *immediate pane* (Ctrl+G), and type `?rs.Fields("Five9 Extension").Value`.

Comment: Either BOF or EOF is true, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record. I

Comment: Yup. As I thought. Answer on the way.

Comment: Thank you! Also, thanks for teaching me the break point thing. I'm still relatively new to all this and self taught so every little trick helps!

Comment: Learning to use the debugger (breakpoints, immediate pane, locals toolwindow, call stack, etc.) is the single most important thing you can learn =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bang operator implicit default member calls aside (`rs![Field Name]` is shorthand for `rs.Fields("Field Name").Value`), it seems the query isn't returning what you think it does:

> ```vb
> SQLStr = "select [Five9 Extension] from dbo.[Master Staffing List] Where [Agent Name] ='" & MainPage.AgentName.Selected(itemIndex) & "'"
> ```

`ListBox.Selected(index)` returns a `Boolean`, so the query you're sending is something like

```sql
select [Five9 Extension] from dbo.[Master Staffing List] Where [Agent Name] ='True'
```

....Which I would expect to yield a grand total of 0 rows.

Question: what would happen if `[Agent Name]` were to be `Jake O'Neil`? That's right, a syntax error with the query. Now what if `[Agent Name]` were to be `Robert'; DROP TABLE [Master Staffing List];--`? That's right, *very bad things*. This is called a *SQL injection vulnerability*, and it plagues database-queryuing code all over the world, whenever people concatenate WHERE clauses with user inputs. It's not only a matter of database security, it's also a cause of easily avoidable bugs.

Let's fix this. Use an `ADODB.Command`, and in your SQL string remove the single quotes and replace the parameter concatenation with a question mark:

```vb
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = Cn
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [Five9 Extension] FROM dbo.[Master StaffingList] WHERE [Agent Name] = ?"
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter(Type:=adVarChar, Value:=selectedName)
Set rs = cmd.Execute
```

Now for consuming the recordset, you can't assume that there will be rows - so you make a `Do While` loop that doesn't enter if `rs.EOF` is `True`:

```vb
Do While Not rs.EOF
    '...consume recordset...
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Now, only `selectedName` needs to be figured out. Use the listbox' `ListIndex` property to do that:

```vb
Dim selectedName As String
With MainPage.AgentName
    Debug.Assert .MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectSingle 'wheels come off otherwise
    selectedName = .List(.ListIndex)
End With
```

Comment: This looks like a much better way of handling that. However, I'm getting a Duplicate Declaration in current scope on the Dim SelectedName as String line.

Comment: Then remove the duplicate `Dim` statement?

Comment: Sorry, It's just that I don't Dim SelectedName anywhere else in the code.

Comment: Perhaps there's a globally-scoped `SelectedName` variable, constant, or procedure, *somewhere* in the project then. Rename the local variable, that error is VBA saying "I already have a definition for that identifier".

Comment: Ok, managed to get it down to having ebug.Assert .MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectSingle give me a method or data member not found error.

Comment: @Jb83 that would be `Debug.Assert`, and that's just me assuming `MainPage.AgentName` is a `ListBox` control. Feel free to delete that line.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! I think I got it down now!